# Returning objects from functions (R)

Tags: r, function, functional-programming, return

I don't understand why this snippet does not work. My understanding of the function `return()` is that it enables you to use an object that was created *inside a function* outside the function.

I have this simple function and I want to use `product` outside of my function. How can I do this?
Or, alternatively, have I entirely missed the point of the `return()` function?

```
simple_fcn<- function(input1, input2)
{
        product = input1*input2
        return(product)
}

simple_fcn(2,5)

print(product)
```

Comment: you have to assign `simple_fcn(2,5)` to an object, otherwise calling this function will only print its output

Comment: i.e. `product <- simple_fcn(2,5)`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to save the return argument when calling the function into a variable that is available in the global environment, i.e. try the following:

```
product_global <- simple_fcn(2, 5)
print(product_global)
```

Comment: Fantastic! Delighted it's such a simple solution. I never knew this. Thanks all for your speedy replies!

Answer (score 1):

In addition to Felipe's comment,
to assign `product` to a variable in a function's parent environment you can do `product <<- product` or `assign('product', product, 1)` inside the function. For more flexible assignments see `?assign`.

Comment: But it's bad practice most of the time